# fix div when window resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a div that has fixed position and bottom 0 to display at the bottom of the window.

My problem is when window resize, this div move to up and into other elements. For example when I open console box in chrome this div jump to other elements in facebook fix position such as friend list, when I open console box, element jump to up but hidden up element.

Please help me how I can fix div in window resize.

Comment: Please post the code or it is impossible to help you.

Comment: Thats a common problem with fixed html elements. You should use a diffrent aproach to achief your need. To help you more informations (html, css, fiddle) would help us to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### CSS Position Fixed:

> Do not leave space for the element. Instead, position it at a
>   specified position relative to the screen's viewport and doesn't move
>   when scrolled. When printing, position it at that fixed position on
>   every page. Fixed positioning is similar to absolute positioning, with
>   the exception that the element's containing block is the viewport.
>   This is often used to create a floating element that stays in the same
>   position even after scrolling the page. - by [Mozilla MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position)

In other words, When you use `position: fixed;` that takes elements out of the document's regular flow.

> How I can fix div in Window Re-size?

**Solution:** There's no way to do it as you want using CSS. You must remove `position: fixed;` because when you set `bottom: 0px` with `position: fixed;` to your element then it doesn't matter that what is the size (vertical) of your browser or window because `position: fixed;` element will always appear on the bottom of the viewport screen at 0px.

Answer (score 0):

You can use
`position: fixed`
or

```
`position:absolute`
```

Comment: He is alreay using position fixed